# Why Java Does not Have Access Specifier based Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

In Java we cannot specify private, protected or public at the time of inheriting a class. For instance the below code is not possible in Java. Why?

```
class A {
    public void display() {
        //Some implementation of display logic.
    }
}

class B extends **protected** A
{
    public void show() {
         display();
         //some more logic.
    }
}

B obj = new B();
obj.show();
```

I does not want to have obj.display() and need to hide its implementation from outside world. In C++ we can have access modifier based inheritance but in java not. My questions is if we want to hide the implementation how can we achieve this?

Why is this architectural decision taken in Java to remove access modifiers during inheritance, what is the harm in using it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with an access modifier for the base class?

Comment: I think he's asking WHY.. in my opinion Ankit, Java was designed to be a Pure OO language.. whereas C++ was designed to support OO paradigm too.. So here Java guys thought that these kind of things in C++ could make things more complex so they left it out..

So if you are still having probs like this means, it is clear that you have not shifted towards Java completely. you are trying to achieve C++ in Java. which is not good.

So i advice you reconsider the OO design of your current prob..

Comment: I do not know `C++` so maybe this made sense in that language but I do not think there would be any benefit from being able to do this in `Java`, it just doesn't make sense

Comment: To override a super class method and reduce it's visibility is in some ways saying that the subclass `is not a` super class. If that's the case, and you need the super functionality, you always have composition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ provides the ability to allow physical inheritance to be used as part of the implementation detail of a class.

This part of C++ was designed *before* Barbara Liskov introduced what is now known as the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). To satisfy the Liskov substitution principle, wherever an instance of the superclass is used, an instance of a subclass may be used as well. In your case, you could pass a B to a method that expected an A.

Java was designed *after* the introduction of this principle. In Java, the physical mechanism of inheritance is used only for classes that are intended to logically inherit from their superclass. To use the implementation of a class, but not its interface, you can use delegation.

From Stroustrup's "The design and evolution of C++":

> "The private/public distinction for base classes predates the debate on implementation inheritance versus interface inheritance by about five years [Synder,1986][Liskov,1987]. If you want to inherit an implementation only, you use private derivation in C++. Public derivation gives users of the derived class access to the interface provided by the base class. Private derivation leaves the base an an implementation detail; even the public members of the base class are inaccessible except through the interface explicitly provided for the derived class."

Comment: Yes I do agree but why is that architectural decision taken for Java.

Comment: One reason (as noted above) is that it would break the Liskov substitution principle.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can't reduce the visibility of a method or field as it would cause issues with passing the subclass to a method that needs the superclass. You may increase it, however.

Let's look at an example:

```
public static void displayFromA(A a){
    a.display();
}
```

Since `B` extends `A` we may pass `B` to this. If `B`'s `display(` method's visibility was reduced this method would not work. This would break the premise of the Liskov substitution principle, formally that if `q(x)` was a truth value for the ability for a method to call `display(` then `q(x)` would hold for `x` as an instance of A, but not necessarily if `x` was a subtype of A.

Comment: @AnkitZalani You can't since that would break supertype compatiblity, in case some method needs a `A` to run `display(` on, but you pass it B. You can only increase the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

One way to prevent access to the underlying display() is to override it.  e.g., in your B class:

```
@Override
public void display() {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Do not use B.display(), please use B.show() instead");
}
```

And, in B, e.g. in show(), call super.display() instead.

However, this will be caught at runtime, not during compilation.  Add some javadocs and hope they read them.  :-)

I don't know of a way to add something like a @NeverCallMe annotation that would have this get caught at compilation.  Anybody know a trick for that?

(added) BTW I agree with Java's designers, and the other answers, that this is something you generally should not do for proper OO-ness, Liskov and all that.  But this is a somewhat kludgy way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to make class B have an "IS-A" relation to class A if you want to hide that information from everyone.

If you just want to re-use the code from class A you can have class B wrap an instance of A and delegate to it like so:

```
class B{
    //this is our delegate to A
    private A myA = new A();

    public void show() {
         myA.display();
         //some more logic.
    }
}

B obj = new B();
obj.show();
```